# Ordering backbone views together with collection

Tags: sorting, backbone.js, collections, view

I have a collection which contains several items that should be accessible in a list.

So every element in the collection gets it own view element which is then added to the DOM into one container.

My question is:
How do I apply the sort order I achieved in the collection with a comparator function to the DOM?
The first rendering is easy: you iterate through the collection and create all views which are then appended to the container element in the correct order.

But what if models get changed and are re-ordered by the collection? What if elements are added? I don't want to re-render ALL elements but rather update/move only the necessary DOM nodes.

Comment: Collection provides `add` event , also when `comparator` is specified the model get's inserted at correct index. You have no other choice than to reflow/repaint the entire collection ( to make it simple)

Comment: Yes I do. Look at the answer below.

Answer (score 7):

### **model add**

The path where elements are added is rather simple, as you get the `index` in the options when a model gets added to a collection. This index is the sorted index, based on that if you have a straightforward view, it should be easy to insert your view at a certain index.

### **sort attribute change**

This one is a bit tricky, and I don't have an answer handy (and I've struggled with this at times as well) because the collection doesn't automatically reshuffle its order after you change an attribute the model got sorted on when you initially added it.

**from the backbone docs:**

> Collections with comparator functions will not automatically re-sort
>   if you **later** change model attributes, so you may wish to call sort
>   after changing model attributes that would affect the order.

so if you call sort on a collection it will trigger a `reset` event which you can hook into to trigger a redraw of the whole list.

It's highly ineffective when dealing with lists that are fairly long and can seriously reduce user experience or even induce hangs

So the few things you get walking away from this is knowing you can:

- always find the index of a model after sorting by calling `collection.indexOf(model)`
- get the index of a model from an `add` event (3rd argument)

Edit:

After thinking about if for a bit I came up with something like this:

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.bind('change:name', this.onChangeName, this);
    },
    onChangeName: function ()
    {
        var index, newIndex;

        index = this.collection.indexOf(this);
        this.collection.sort({silent: true});
        newIndex = this.collection.indexOf(this);
        if (index !== newIndex)
        {
            this.trigger('reindex', newIndex);
            // or
            // this.collection.trigger('reindex', this, newIndex);

        }
    }
});
```

and then in your view you could listen to

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.model.bind('reindex', this.onReindex, this);
    },
    onReindex: function (newIndex)
    {
        // execute some code that puts the view in the right place ilke
        $("ul li").eq(newIndex).after(this.$el);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah, the add is pretty easy - the resort is the difficult problem. I had something similiar in mind for the backbone side, but the HARD stuff is where you only left a comment. "Some code that puts the view in the right place" :D

Comment: Would this be still preferable when handling a full list resorting?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Vincent for an awesome solution. There's however a problem with the moving of the element, depending on which direction the reindexed element is moving. If it's moving down, the index of the new location doesn't match the index of what's in the DOM. This fixes it:

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.bind('change:name', this.onChangeName, this);
    },
    onChangeName: function () {
        var fromIndex, toIndex;

        fromIndex = this.collection.indexOf(this);
        this.collection.sort({silent: true});
        toIndex = this.collection.indexOf(this);
        if (fromIndex !== toIndex)
        {
            this.trigger('reindex', fromIndex, toIndex);
            // or
            // this.collection.trigger('reindex', this, fromIndex, toIndex);
        }
    }
});
```

And the example listening part:

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.model.bind('reindex', this.onReindex, this);
    },
    onReindex: function (fromIndex, toIndex) {
        var $movingEl, $replacingEl;

        $movingEl = this.$el;
        $replacingEl = $("ul li").eq(newIndex);

        if (fromIndex < toIndex) {
            $replacingEl.after($movingEl);
        } else {
            $replacingEl.before($movingEl);
        }
    }
});
```